# Reacting mouse click event in viewModel instead of code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF app where a list view is set via a ViewModel.

I have something like the code below to handle a mouse click on the list view but I have read iot would be better to handle this in the view model instead of the code behind?

I have code like below

XAML:

```
<ListView ... PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="listView_Click"> ...
```

Code behind:

```
private void listView_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = (sender as ListView).SelectedItem;
    if (item != null)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I tried have something like the code below but is there a way to move it to the view model avoiding the code behind completely?

```
public void listView_Click(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = (sender as ListView).SelectedItem;
    if (item != null)
    {
        Record record = item.DataContext as Record;
        if (record != null)
        {
            MyViewModel viewModel = ((MyViewModel)this.DataContext);
            var result = viewModel.performWork(record);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Record is a ListViewItem

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: One possible solution: Bind the `ListView.SelectedItem` property to a property of type `Record` in your ViewModel (such as `SelectedRecord`) and perform your work when the selected record changes. This removes the need to handle events, since you're  actually working with the `data` rather than UI events

Comment: @HighCore that's pretty much the only acceptable MVVM solution.

Comment: @HighCore why don't you add that as an answer?

Comment: Agreed, @HighCore is right. But that being said... You can also bind Commands to Events using `EventTrigger` and `InvokeCommandAction` from the `interactivity` namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the `ListView.SelectedItem` property to a property of type `Record` in your ViewModel (such as `SelectedRecord`) and perform your work when the selected 
record changes:

XAML:

```
<ListView .... 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRecord}"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
private Record _selectedRecord;
public Record SelectedRecord
{
    get { return _selectedRecord; }
    set
    {
        _selectedRecord = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();

        // Call your DoWork() method here
        this.DoWork();
    }
}
```